# How can I run a .exe file every hour automatically?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, .net

I'm using Windows Server 2008 R2.

I've created a .NET console application and deployed it to the server. If I double click the .exe application, it runs well and does it's job.

This application has to update values on a database. I need to be able to run this every hour automatically.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Look at the acepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3243348/how-to-call-a-method-daily-at-specific-time-in-c
This includes also the option to run it programmatically in .net

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The windows task scheduler allows you to regularly run a program.  It's in the control panel under administrative tools, or in server manager under configuration.

Just click create task, add a trigger for "On a schedule" and in advanced settings choose "Repeat task every 1 hour for a duration of Indefinitely"

Under actions, add one for start a program and specify your program and any needed arguments

On the first tab, you will probably want to choose "Run whether user is logged on or not" and choose a user to run it as.

Answer (score 2):

You should use Windows Task Scheduler for that. You can check [this](http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles_tutorials/Working-Windows-Server-2008-Task-Scheduler-Part1.html) tutorial to get started.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Task Scheduler](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766428.aspx). It's pretty straightforward.